# How can I export MATLABPATH and call matlab function through the same python subprocess?

Tags: python, matlab

I need to call matlab with a defined MATLABPATH from a python script and I try to do this with the following code (snippet) in python:

```
addMatlabPath = os.path.join(<validPath>,'src') + ":" + \
              os.path.join(<someOtherValidPaht>,'src') + ":"
matlabPathCommand = "export MATLABPATH="+addMatlabPath+"$MATLABPATH"
commandLine = matlabPathCommand+" && echo $MATLABPATH && "+"/Applications/MATLAB_R2015a.app/bin/matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -r \"my_matlab_script\"".format(os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)),output_dir)
```

I try to execute the commandLine through subprocess:

```
process = subprocess.check_call(commandLine, stdout=out_buffer, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=True)
```

with which I can call matlab perfectly without the `matlabPathCommand` and the echo part in front.

The paths I use for the variable `addMatlabPath` are valid. I tested the command `matlabPathCommand+ && echo $MATLABPPATH` and this works correctly.

So, both parts of the command work individually as expected but not together. Python seems to hang in the check_call command and doesn't return even after a multiple of time the call to matlab normally takes.

Does anyone have a hint where my error could be?

Answer (score 0):

The python code snippet above is correct. There was a problem in the matlab code which I didn't recognise while testing. This question and answer can be deleted.